# Why is protos.h file needed by the MDs?

Tags: gcc

why do you need the protos.h file in machine descriptions?. I know that it contains all the forward declarations for the functions in the C file. But cant we do without it?

Thanks,
Isha.

Comment: Why don't you tell us why you don't want it?

Comment: Actually its not that I don't want it, I wanted to know its significance. I was looking at machine description files, and I was wondering why it is necessary. I searched in the internal documents but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

The machine description files can include any C code (for example, as part of pattern conditions). Because this C code could be calling functions (and it sometimes is), you need to have correct prototypes. Hence the need to include `protos.h`.